# Why am I unable to press the UIButton inside of my UIPickerView?

Tags: swift, xcode, button, uipickerview, toolbar

I have a `UIPickerView` with a `UIToolBar` item added to it (<kbd>Done</kbd> Button). But when I select the button, it's supposed to print something to the console via `#selector(dismissKeyboard)`, and yet it doesn't.

I'm relatively new to Swift and I'm doing everything programmatically, so I'm just having a bit of a hard time figuring out why I cannot interact with the button that's added as a subview to my `pickerView`.

Here is the relevant code that I'm working with... Please let me know if you need more info...

As a side, I already assigned the delegate and datasource for the `pickerView`, and I call the `createToolBar()` function inside the `viewDidLoad`.

```
    var timerImage = UIButton()
    var timer = Timer()
    var timerDisplayed = 0
    let image1 = UIImage(named: "stopwatch")
    let timePicker = UIPickerView()

    @objc func dismissKeyboard(){
        print("PickerView Dismissed")
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func pickerViewConstraints(){
        timePicker.anchor(top: nil, leading: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
    }

    func createToolBar(){
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))

        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
        toolBar.isTranslucent = false
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        timePicker.addSubview(toolBar)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(toolBar)    
    }

    @objc func timeClock(){
        view.addSubview(timePicker)
        pickerViewConstraints()
        timePicker.backgroundColor = .white

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.Action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            self.timerImage.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Something else that I realized, that when I try to change the background colour of the ToolBar to blue, the colour doesn't change. I'm guessing that the issue is related to overlapping views...

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you haven't technically called `print` in the function. If you want something to print in the console, the code should look something like this:

```
   { error in 
     if let error = error {
       print("Error")
         }
     }
```

(This can be contained within your `DispatchQueue`) If it's not an error you're reporting to yourself, just having something along the lines of —

```
 } else {
   print("Button Tapped")
     }
  }
```

— should also work. I hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate the advice. What I'm looking for is a simple print statement upon pressing the "Done" barButtonItem, as I'm not checking for any errors. 

So am I writing this bit of code wrong?  

  
`let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
        
@objc func dismissKeyboard(){
        print("PickerView Dismissed")
        view.endEditing(true)
    }`

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're saying. To be honest, I haven't had experience with adding a print-console button directly onto a Toolbar. The code you have as-is won't work, as far as I know. 

I believe you have to create an if / else to the "print" to apply to the actual button. 

I have created some similar buttons / functions. I'm linking it here:

https://github.com/kcapretta/RadiusSocialNetworkingApp/blob/master/NewProfile/datingOptionViewController

I haven't figured it out, but maybe you can chop up this code and make something work? Sorry I can't be of more help :(